# How to loop through selected elements with document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying loop on selected elements that queried with document.querySelectorAll, but how?

For example I use:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
for( i in checkboxes) {
  console.log(checkboxes[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
<input id="check-1" class="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
<input id="check-2" class="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
<input id="check-3" class="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
<input id="check-4" class="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
<input id="check-5" class="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
<input id="check-6" class="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
<input id="check-7" class="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
<input id="check-8" class="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
<input id="check-9" class="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
<input id="check-10" class="check" type="checkbox" name="check" checked="">

10
item()
namedItem()
```

My problem is that at the end this method returns 3 extra items. How can I properly do it?

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure I understand your problem... Could you post your HTML code and the result you get more clearly?

Comment: This article should explain it pretty well: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList This second link warns of your attempted approach. Use `[index]`, `for (...of...)`, `.forEach(function () {})`, or `.item(index)`, for the easiest methods.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`for in` loop is not recommended for arrays and array-like objects - you see why. There can be more than just number-indexed items, for example the `length` property or some methods, but `for in` will loop through all of them. Use either

```
for (var i = 0, len = checkboxes.length; i < len; i++) {
    //work with checkboxes[i]
}
```

or

```
for (var i = 0, element; element = checkboxes[i]; i++) {
    //work with element
}
```

The second way can't be used if some elements in array can be falsy (not your case), but can be more readable because you don't need to use `[]` notation everywhere.

Comment: Modern update: ES6 has introduced additional possibilities (`for of`, `[...spread]`, …), and the ES5 `[].forEach(…)` hack does continue to work, beyond modern browsers (see another answer here) **all** supporting `NodeList.forEach`.

Answer (score 99):

My favorite is using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to convert the NodeList to an array and then use `forEach` for looping.

```
var div_list = document.querySelectorAll('div'); // returns NodeList
var div_array = [...div_list]; // converts NodeList to Array
div_array.forEach(div => {

// do something awesome with each div

});
```

I code in ES2015 and use Babel.js, so there shouldn't be a browser support issue.

Comment: Here's to a modern answer.

Comment: Typescript shows error `Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is not an array type`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '...'

Comment: Now that there's broad browser support for NodeList.forEach, this is the best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42494126/7920. See also: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_nodelist_foreach

Comment: `var` is modern?

Answer (score 61):

It looks like Firefox 50+, Chrome 51+ and Safari 10+ now all support the `.forEach` function for `NodeList` objects. Note—**`.forEach` is not supported in Internet Explorer**, so consider one of the approaches above or use a polyfill if IE support is required.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

```js
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
paragraphs.forEach(p => console.log(p));
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
```

Comment: or `[...document.querySelectorAll('p')].forEach(p => console.log(p));`

Comment: In 2023, I believe this is now the right approach. No need for spread, `Array.from` or `for in`

Answer (score 32):

With **ES6**, there is a static method `Array.from` to take advantages of `Array` non-static methods (map, filter, ...) :

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).forEach((element,index) =>
{

     // handle "element"

});
```

Another use of `Array.from` since `querySelector` provides `item` method:

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll('div');
// create range [0,1,2,....,all.length-1]
Array.from({length: all.length}, (v, k) => k).forEach((index) => {
     let element = all.item(index);
});
```

Comment: But you can just do `document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(item => console.log(item))` ... why do you need to wrap it with `Array.from` ?

Comment: @vsync you wouldn't need to wrap for `.forEach`, but would if you wanted to use another Array method like `.map` or `.filter` because `.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, and not an `Array`. I'd choose this approach if I wanted to make sure I was working with arrays and wanted to keep data/API calls consistent.

Comment: Then ```[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].forEach((element,index) =>
{

     // handle "element"

});``` could do it

Comment: @djibe are dots `...` necessary to make it work ?

Comment: @Salem. Yes it seems as `document.querySelectorAll` stores a nodeList and we send it to `Array.forEach` method. In one line we get the nodeList, destructure it in an array and send it to forEach method.

Answer (score 26):

A nice alternative is:

```
[].forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('.check'),
    function (el) {
        console.log(el);
    }
);
```

but as pointed out, you should use a for loop.

Comment: The overhead is more than just using a for loop unfortunately, it's a neat solution though.

Comment: Interesting post on this method: http://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/

Comment: If taking this approach, it would be best to do the `querySelectorAll` before and pass the result into the `forEach` loop (eg. `var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.check'); [].forEach.call(elements, ...);`). Otherwise you end up unnecessarily making the same DOM query over and over again on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

### A Main Takeaway:

#### The type matters.

`.map` will not work directly on a `NodeList` but will on an `Array`.

Compare these:
[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
[`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

### Options:

#### ES6 available?

1. The spread operator `[...element_list]` then `Array.map()`
2. `Array.from()` on a `NodeList.forEach()`

#### ES6 NOT available?

1. `NodeList.forEach()`
2. A "`for` loop"

Answer (score 6):

```
// for class
for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('[class=".check"]')){
    //work as per usual
};

// for name
for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('[name="check"]')){
    //work as per usual
};

// for id
for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('[id="check-1"]')){
    //work as per usual
};
```

This provides me with flexibility on what element I would like to work with.

Comment: Your first example won't work. The value `.check` won't match anything and would only match class attributes with that exact value (not with other classes). It should just be `querySelectorAll('.check')`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the most clean and accessible is the `for...of` statement, this perfect syntax executes a loop that operates on a sequence of values sourced from an iterable object. The second options for me is the `three-dots` operator (`...`), if ES6 is available, this is also a very good options as my personal opinion. Finally, `forEach` if you are building big app and you want to provide support for most of the browsers out there this might give you some headaches.

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('li')

let results = {
  'for': [],
  'forEach': [],
  'three-dots': [],
}

// ES6 bellow
for (const li of lis) {
  results['for'].push(li)
}

// ES6 above
[...lis].forEach((li) => results['three-dots'].push(li))

// Most browsers support it 
lis.forEach(li => results['forEach'].push(li))

console.log({results})
```

```html
<u>
  <li>Item 01</li>
  <li>Item 02</li>
  <li>Item 03</li>
  <li>Item 04</li>
  <li>Item 05</li>
  <li>Item 06</li>
  <li>Item 07</li>
  <li>Item 08</li>
</u>
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and cleanest way to be able to use any regular Array methods, or in your case a `for in` loop on a `NodeList`, is to spread it into an array as you fetch it:

```js
const checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.check')];

for (i in checkboxes) {
  console.log(checkboxes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

U can select all elements using `querySelectorAll` method. It will return an array of nodeList.

Lets say u want to select all p tags

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
```

```js
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
```

Now the paragraphs has a forEach method which can be used to loop through the nodelist

```
paragraphs.forEach(console.log); (logs node)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community pls check the answer clearly before doing any comments. Stack overflow please check this bot bug