# javascript, finding a DOM element repeatedly

Tags: javascript, loops, dom, recursive-datastructures

For a given amount of html nodes, such as

```
<div id="main">
 <div class="pre1">
  <div class="prop1"></div>
  <div class="prop2"></div>
  <div class="prop3"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="pre2">
  <div class="prop1"></div>
  <div class="prop2"></div>
  <div class="prop3"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="pre3">
  <div class="prop1"></div>
  <div class="prop2"></div>
  <div class="prop3"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The way to add text to the prop2 nodes would be something like

```
var el = document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild;
while (el) {
  var el2 = el.firstElementChild;
  while (el2) {
    if (el2.className == 'prop2')
      el2.textContent = 'hola';
      el2 = el2.nextElementSibling;
  }
  el = el.nextElementSibling;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g9zoa1vz/

The problem is that conceptually, the first time that you locate the 'prop2' item, if you know that your data structure is constant, you are wasting time in searching again the position.

The question is: Is there a way to store the DOM location so that after your first search, then you can do something like

```
var el = document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild;
while (el) {
  el.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.textContent = 'hola';
  el = el.nextElementSibling;
}
```

and then saving significant loop-time when many nodes are to be analyzed?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".prop2").forEach(function() {})` Your question is an X/Y problem...

Comment: You can push necessary elements into array, and then just iterate over it.

Comment: You know you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.prop2')` to get all of your `prop2` nodes at once, right? You can even be more specific: `document.querySelectorAll('.pre1 > .prop2')` will get only those nodes that are direct children of `pre1`...

Comment: To be honest, if this bit of code is not bottlenecking the performance of your application I won't be too bothered about optimizing it. Are we talking about 100k of nodes; where it is slowing down the application drastically?

Comment: @SamuelToh it was more a theoretical question, but I have already applied the solution to a function in my code and now instead of waiting 1 second it happens instantaneously (and it actually is a significant deal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Note we use a for loop to iterate although some browsers will allow forEach.

More ways to iterate: [How to loop through selected elements with document.querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall)

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var prop2 = document.querySelectorAll("#main .prop2");
  for (var i=0, n=prop2.length; i<n; i++) {
    prop2[i].innerHTML="hola";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
 <div class="pre1">
  <div class="prop1"></div>
  <div class="prop2"></div>
  <div class="prop3"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="pre2">
  <div class="prop1"></div>
  <div class="prop2"></div>
  <div class="prop3"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="pre3">
  <div class="prop1"></div>
  <div class="prop2"></div>
  <div class="prop3"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: forEach is an array function, querySelectorAll returns a nodeList. EDIT: ok, good fix ;)

Comment: Chrome actually allows this

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, I had known about it but it was long forgotten, so thanks a lot. I can assume that the nodeList will be sorted always by order of appearance?

Comment: Yes. It is like a jQuery $("#main .prop2)

Comment: I have updated my answer to only get the length once.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```js
   var ele=document.querySelectorAll(".prop2");
   var l=ele.length;
   for(i=0;i<l;i++){
    ele[i].innerHTML="hello";
   }
```

Comment: yes its like same to me. I am late in giving answer.

Comment: Because Its not optimize code whenever loop execute it calculate length. If loop execute 100000 times then its length calculation is done 100000 time. if we define length before then it calculate only once.

Comment: `var ele=document.querySelectorAll(".prop2");
var l=ele.length; for (....)` makes more sense

Comment: please see my above comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121887/discussion-between-rakesh-sojitra-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I see what you meant to do: `for (var i=0, n=ele.length; i<n; i++) {`