# Why is forEach method breaking in IE?

Tags: javascript

Works well on chrome/Firefox and only breaks on the second forEach and only on IE(I'm testing on IE11 ).

> Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

```
    moment(da).weekdaysInBetween(moment(da).add(14, 'day').format('MM/DD/YYYY')).forEach(function(nextDay){
   //console.log('first');
        thirteen.push(nextDay.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    });


   document.querySelectorAll('input[class="newname"]').forEach(function(input, index){
        input.value = thirteen[index];
      //  console.log('second');
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through selected elements with document.querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ECMAScript standards:

> The forEach function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the forEach function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.

IE is saying it does not support `.forEach` on the node list returned by the query. You can call `Array.prototype.forEach` on the list instead, as in this cut-down example:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call( 
     document.querySelectorAll('input'),
     function(input, index){
        input.value = 'hello ' + index;
     }
);
```

```html
<input type="text"><input type="text">
```

Comment: I don't recall if IE supports it, but `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).forEach(...)` is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll dont return a array, it return a NodeList and you can't use forEach in a NodeList, you need to convert the NodeList in array using Array.prototype.slice.apply, try the following:

```
moment(da).weekdaysInBetween(moment(da).add(14, 'day').format('MM/DD/YYYY')).forEach(function(nextDay){
   //console.log('first');
        thirteen.push(nextDay.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    });


   Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('input[class="newname"]')).forEach(function(input, index){
        input.value = thirteen[index];
      //  console.log('second');
    })
```

;

If .forEach() isn't supported you can use the following code to replace forEach

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.18
// Reference: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {

  Array.prototype.forEach = function forEach(callback, thisArg) {
    'use strict';
    var T, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError("this is null or not defined");
    }

    var kValue,
        // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| value as the argument.
        O = Object(this),

        // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with the argument "length".
        // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
        len = O.length >>> 0; // Hack to convert O.length to a UInt32

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if ({}.toString.call(callback) !== "[object Function]") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + " is not a function");
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length >= 2) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 7. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Call the Call internal method of callback with T as the this value and
        // argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
        callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }
    // 8. return undefined
  };
}
```

More Info in mozilla developer network