# Javascript - forEach() loops not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, foreach, internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-5

forEach loops are supposed to be working in IE11 and diplay

> Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'.

It should be working since it's an ECMAScript-5 function and [IE11 supports it](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/).

However, my code here is not working:

```
var alltable = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="table_"]'); //Select all elements with the id starting by "table_"
    alltable.forEach(function(element) {
                // Do some code
                });
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: the title is a bit misleading ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is forEach method breaking in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354000/why-is-foreach-method-breaking-in-ie)

Comment: Well, how would you call it ? That was my problem and I just wanted to help other who encounter the same...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well myself,

**forEach() is actually working on IE11**, just be careful on how you call it.

*querySelectorAll()* is a method which return a **NodeList**. 
 And on Internet Explorer, ***foreach()* only works on Array** objects. (It works with NodeList with ES6, [not supported by IE11)](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

To fix this, some would advice a polyfill, which could work great, but you can also simply convert your NodeList into an array with the slice.call() method: [(Explained here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125714/explanation-of-slice-call-in-javascript)

```
var alltable = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="table_"]'); //Select all elements with the id starting by "table_"
var alltableArray= Array.prototype.slice.call(alltable);
    alltableArray.forEach(function(element) {
                // Do some code
                });
```

Or:

```
var alltable = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="table_"]')); //Select all elements with the id starting by "table_"
    alltable.forEach(function(element) {
                // Do some code
                });
```

To sum up:
***Be sure you're using it on an Array object and not a NodeList.***

Hope that can help someone.