# How to apply one function to multiple instances of a class

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, frontend

I want to apply this 'coupon-clipping' function to multiple elements on this page without making a separate function for each different element. On the code snippet I added, it works for my first "Buy 4, Save $2.00" but not for the "4 Coupons".

From my research I know that this

```
var coupon1 = document.querySelector('.coupon1');
```

just returns the FIRST instance of the coupon1 but I need to figure out how to apply that function to ALL elements of that class (say 20 elements of the coupon1 class).

```js
var coupon1 = document.querySelector('.coupon1');
var coupon2 = document.querySelector('.coupon2');

coupon1 ? coupon1
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    coupon1.remove();
    coupon2.classList.remove('hide-coupon');
  }) : false;
```

```html
<div class="coupon-product coupon1">
  <span id="coupon">Buy 4, Save $2.00</span>
</div>

<div class="coupon-product-clipped hide-coupon coupon2">
  <span id="clipped-coupon">Buy 4, Save $2.00</span>
</div>


<div class="coupon-product coupon1">
  <span id="coupon">4 Coupons</span>
</div>
<div class="coupon-product-clipped hide-coupon coupon2">
  <span id="clipped-coupon">4 Coupons</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `.querySelector()` is **not** a jQuery method; it's built-in to browsers. That said, you're looking for `.querySelectorAll()` which returns a list of elements.

Comment: If you get an array of elements, just iterate on each items.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` and loop over the collection of elements to bind the `click` event.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.coupon1').forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {...});
})
```

As **@pointy** mentioned, some enviroments don't support Array iteration methods on NodeList objects, so, you can use the function `Array.from`.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.coupon1')).forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {...});
})
```

**Or something like this:** [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.coupon1')
Array.from({ elements.length }, function(_, i) { return i}).forEach(function(index) {
    let elem = elements.item(index);
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {...});
});
```

Comment: Aren't there some environments that don't support the Array iteration methods on NodeList objects?

Comment: @Pointy yes, we can use use the function `Array.from`

Comment: Hmm...for some reason whenever I use any of those functions then NEITHER of the instance from my 'coupon1' class work... I am at a complete loss for why that doesn't work because the logic makes sense. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I also have multiple instances of coupon2 so i wonder if i have to do some manipulating with that as well. but thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".coupon1").each(function(idx, elem){
    elem.click(function()
    {
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, but jQuery will iterate for you automatically; you don't need the `.each()` unless you need to do different things for each element.

Answer (score 0):

$('.coupon1').click(function() { stuff here}) doesn't do the job?

You could imagine:

```
$('.coupon1').click(function() { 
   $(this).hide();
   $('.coupon2').show();
)})
```

or even with a common class 'coupon':

```
$('.coupon').click(function() { 
   $('.coupon1').toggle();
   $('.coupon2').toggle();
)})
```

to alternate but maybe not needed

Regard

Answer (score 0):

Apply to as many elements as you want using jQuery class selector, as such:

```
var elements = $(".coupon1")
```

Now you can bind click event, as such:

```
elements.click(function(){
    var clickedCoupon = $(this);
    var allOtherCoupons = $(".coupon1").not(this);
})
```