# Replace lines ending with semicolon

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace, in JavaScript, all lines that ends with semicolon `;` with `<li>$1</li>`.

Example:

```
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three;</p>
<p>four;</p>
<p>five</p>
```

Would become:

```
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
<p>five</p>
```

*(I don't have newlines, but `<p>first</p><p>second</p>etc.`)*

I tried with this regex:

```
/<p>(.*?;)<\/p>/
```

but this match from the first `<p>`.

*I would also like to wrap them in `<ul></ul>` but I think this is super advanced.*

Comment: Use a parser - [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Related -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex here, just loop over DOM elements and test whether or not they end in `;`. If they do, slice it off!

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  if(p[i].textContent.endsWith(';')) {
    var x = document.createElement('li')
    x.textContent = p[i].textContent.slice(0,-1)
    p[i].parentNode.insertBefore(x,p[i])
    p[i].parentNode.removeChild(p[i])
    i--
  }
}
```

```html
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three;</p>
<p>four;</p>
<p>five</p>
```

Comment: @Jan ok I've change it to create `li`

Comment: plus one for the parser way (hey, that was my part ;-) !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regular expressions, it would be better to simply use the appropriate DOM manipulation methods.
If you need older browser support, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall) on how to replace the `for..of` loop.

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('p');
const matcher = new RegExp(';$');

for (const node of nodes) {
  if (!node.textContent.match(matcher)) continue;
  const newNode = document.createElement('li');
  newNode.textContent = node.textContent.replace(matcher, '');
  node.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, node);
}
```

```html
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three;</p>
<p>four;</p>
<p>five</p>
```