# Change All Elements Within Node List

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, styles

I am trying to change the colors of each element(button) within a node list with one line of code.  First, I made the node list:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

Now what I would like to do is change the color of each of the buttons, with one line of code.  I tried

```
buttons.style.color = "green";
```

This returns an error saying that buttons is undefined.  I assume that it's not possible to change all elements with that line of code, and I have been unable to find another way to do so.  So if anyone knows, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since the marked duplicate doesn't really answer the question ...
You must iterate over the elements, either using a loop or something like `forEach`. You should check your browser compatibility restrictions, but a "modern" solution would be
`document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el => el.style.color = 'green')`.

Comment: @Damon the duplicate questions answer perfectly this question [if of course we take the time to read them] ... as a side note the code you shared is already in those duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44874457/8620333 which confirm it's a perfect duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif the second link only showed up after I made that comment, I was referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid which is not relevant

Comment: but yes this has been answered many times elsewhere:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall

Answer (score 0):

with [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('button')); you get an Array and its more easy to work with arrays than nodelist