# Jquery error only on IE11 - Syntax Error Foreach(anchor)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using this code but it errors out in IE11. It seems to work fine on all other browsers including IE Edge. What could be wrong?

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});
```

On the console, I get a syntax error on this line:

```
forEach(anchor =>
```

Comment: IE 11 does not support arrow functions.  Use a normal function for the callbacks

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Arrow function" not working in IE, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/arrow-function-not-working-in-ie-why)

Comment: thanks for this, I have read this thread but I am having difficulties applying it to my particular example.

Comment: `.forEach(anchor => {` is using an arrow function.  Use a normal function, just like you are for the click callback.  `forEach(function(anchor){});`

Comment: I tried that, but now I am getting error: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

Comment: Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to modify your code as below:

```
<a href="#top" data-value="linkA"> Link A</a><br />
<a href="#middle" data-value="linkB"> Link B</a><br />
<a href="#bottom" data-value="linkC"> Link C</a><br />

<div id="top" style="width:100%; height:600px; background-color:antiquewhite">
    Top
</div>
<div id="middle" style="width:100%; height:600px; background-color:aqua">
    Middle
</div>
<div id="bottom" style="width:100%; height:600px; background-color:aquamarine">
    Bottom
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
    forEach.call(anchors, function (anchor) {
        anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //get the a tag attribute.
            alert(e.srcElement.getAttribute("data-value"));
            //document.querySelector(e.srcElement.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
            //    behavior: 'smooth'
            //});
        });

    });
</script>
```

The output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPWqH.gif) (works well on IE, Chrome and Edge).

Besides, please check your code, if we want to get the attribute in the anchor click event, we should use the 'e.srcElement.getAttribute()' method.