# How do I change the background colour of a page in HTML?

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to HTML/CSS/JavaScript and I was wondering how I could change the background colour, with a combination of JavaScript? I have 3 buttons (red, green and blue), and whenever the user presses on one of the three buttons, the background should change accordingly.

Currently, only the 'red' button works. The background doesn't change for the blue and green buttons.

Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id = "red" value = "red">R</button>
        <button id = "green" value = "green">G</button>
        <button id = "blue" value = "blue">B</button>
        <script>
            document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
                document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = this.value;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach()`

Comment: @marzelin is forEach part of the return value for querySelectorAll?

Comment: ``forEach`` is a method that applies to list/array to iterate through each item in the list/array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where should I write '.onclick' if I put forEach() instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use: [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then [loop through selected elements with `document.queryselectorall`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id = "red" value = "red">R</button>
        <button id = "green" value = "green">G</button>
        <button id = "blue" value = "blue">B</button>
        <script>
            document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(element) {
                element.onclick = function() {
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Small note:
Use `document.body` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body)) instead of `document.querySelector('body')` to speed things up ;)

Comment: `document.querySelector('body')` should be stored outside of the listener for better performance.

Comment: btw, you don't have query for `body`, use `document.body`.

Comment: I've used `document.querySelctor` because OP was using it, shameful copy paste ;)

Comment: Could the silent down-voter please clarify how I should improve my answer?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What exactly does 'function(element) do? Does that refer to one line, e.g. <button id = "red" value = "red">R</button> ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick
```

Only adds the event to the first button, in this case red

The are a few ways to do it for all of them, one way is

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')).forEach(x=> x .onclick = function() {
                document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = this.value;
            })
```

Comment: You don't need `Array.from` to use `forEach`. Node list has this method.

Comment: Any advantage to convert node list to array? I only see disadvantage because of creating a shallow copy.

Comment: @ashilsh on my sightly older browser nodelist didn't have forEach

Comment: I think Array.form was added later and doesn't supports the old browser.

Comment: fortunately for you, it has `Array.from`.  Let's go all the way down to IE8 and use `for` loop :)

Comment: @ashiish but was it added before nodelist forEach?

Comment: No worries :D :D

Comment: For support old browser better use [polyfill forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill) same for [Array.form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill)
_Array.from() was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 6th Edition (ES2015)._

Comment: @greg array.from was added much before nodelist forEach https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: @ashiish array.from was added much before nodelist forEach developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/… developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Both are not supported in IE & the good news is IE will no longer be backed my Microsoft so no worries with any method. :)

Comment: @ashiish I don't care for IE answer is mainly for other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Your code not working because `querySelector()` method returns only the first element that matches. For further details, check here: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeBackground(button){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = button.value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id = "red" value = "red" onclick="changeBackground(this);">R</button>
    <button id = "green" value = "green"onclick="changeBackground(this);">G</button>
    <button id = "blue" value = "blue"onclick="changeBackground(this);">B</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here we are calling `changeBackground()` method with current button as parameter on button click. In the method, value of clicked button is used to set style of document's body.

Comment: mixing javascript with html in `onclick` attribute is not ideal.