# why the localstorage not function?

Tags: jquery, cookies

Anyone is able to help us to solve why the localstorage is not functioning for the below

```
           Try a lot of ways nothing win. The reason is very simple DON'T KNOW THE RIGHT WAY ?
```

BELOW IS THE STYLE APPLIED

```
<style>


.div1 {
  background-color: #ff0;width:150px;height:150px;
}
</style>
```

Below is the HTML

```
<input type="color" id="colorit" onchange="setColor()"/>
<div class="div1">
  
</div>
```

AND FINALLY THE SCRIPT

```
<script>

$(".div1").localStorage.getItem('bgcolor') ;
 var ClassName;

function setColor() {
  //localStorage.setItem('background', $('#colorit').val());
  ClassName = $('#colorit').val();
  $('.div1').css('background-color', ClassName);
   localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'ClassName');
}

function getColor() {
  //localStorage.getItem('background');
  $('#colorit').val(ClassName);
 localStorage.getItem('bgcolor') ;
}

setColor();

</script>
```

Comment: Consider not using `getElementById`? Use `querySelectorAll` instead then the desired selector will work (the result should be an "array-like" object)

Comment: like this document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(even)').style ?

Comment: No, not like that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 0):

By using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you can get a list of all the elements. By wrapping this in an array you can iterate it easily.
The natural [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that gets returned by [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) may not be easily iterable/mappable/other array functions, hence the wrapping in an array with the spread operator, so you have more options avaialable.

```js
/** stack overflow localstorage faker **/
stackOverflowlocalStorage = { 
   backColor: null, 
   setItem : function(name, val) {this[name] = val;
   }
 }
/** end polyfill **/
// on input, get value and save it as 'backValue'
function changeback() { 
  var backColor = document.getElementById('revenb').value;
  [...document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(even)')].forEach((element, index) => {
     element.style.backgroundColor = backColor;
  });
  stackOverflowlocalStorage.setItem('backValue', backColor);
}

// uncomment to test  stackOverflowlocalStorage.backValue
// stackOverflowlocalStorage.backValue = '#00ffff';

// if there is a value stored, update color picker and background color
if(stackOverflowlocalStorage.backValue) {
  document.getElementById('revenb').value = stackOverflowlocalStorage.backValue;
  [...document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(even)')].forEach((element, index) => {
     element.style.backgroundColor = stackOverflowlocalStorage.backValue;
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="revenb" onchange="changeback()"/>
<table>
  <tr><td> row 1 </td></tr>
  <tr><td> row 2 </td></tr>
  <tr><td> row 3 </td></tr>
  <tr><td> row 4 </td></tr>
  <tr><td> row 5 </td></tr>
  <tr><td> row 6 </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me as i used here as follows

Comment: function changeback() { 
  var backColor = document.getElementById('revenb').value;
  localStorage.setItem('backValue', document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(even)').style.backgroundColor = backColor);
}

Comment: The answer is correct. @varghese please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return as you're trying to use an array of elements like a normal element.

Comment: Also put an id for the table and then try like this function changeback() { 
  var backColor = document.getElementById('revenb').value;
  localStorage.setItem('backValue', document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:nth-child(even)').style.backgroundColor = backColor);
} but not working

Comment: Please read the linked question. You cannot use `.style` directly after `querySelectorAll`. The link explains why.

Comment: The comments above go like this: "A: do this" "OP: no it doesn't work when I do something completely different".

Comment: @varghese I've adapted the code to work with your modified question code. I hope you can now see how the code is supposed to work.

Comment: Tschallacka, thanks for solving the first part. Now the rows change color but cookie is not functioning. Any solution ?

Comment: @varghese You need to replace stackOverflowlocalStorage for localStorage. I needed a drop in for the sandbox stack overflow snippets run in. How you save your value you can solve with your oiriginal solution via localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Example using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:nth-child(even)')
```

```js
let els = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:nth-child(even)');
[...els].forEach((e) => {
    console.log(e.textContent);
});
```

```html
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <th>Foo</th>
    <th>Bar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even 1</td>
    <td>even 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd 1</td>
    <td>odd 2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>even 3</td>
    <td>even 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- [How to loop through selected elements with document.querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall)

Comment: other details for the question

Comment: Rows Even Background-Color :
    <input type="color"  id="revenb" />

Comment: function changeback() { 
  var backColor = document.getElementById('revenb').value;
  localStorage.setItem('backValue', document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(even)').style.backgroundColor = backColor);
}

Comment: if(localStorage.frontValue) {
  document.getElementById('input#revenc').value = localStorage.frontValue;
  document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(even)').style.color      = localStorage.frontValue;
};

Comment: Please edit your original question to add **all** the details, comments are not suitable for code.

Comment: Please format the code, this is not a free coding service, we're here to help, but you're required to show your own research and failed attempts.

Comment: don't understand ? explain if possible to make me understand.